# WPF Vertical WrapPanel stretch to fill space

Tags: wpf, windows, wrappanel

I want to build a WrapPanel with some elements, e.g. labels, and I while they are all beneath on another, I want the to fill the entire horizontal space.
As far as I can tell, the WrapPanel fills the space itself, but the elements themselves don't.
Does anyone have an idea/ solution how I could achieve this? [It should look this way.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYAZJ.jpg)

Comment: Please provide a code example of what you're trying to do and we can build it from there. Check the documentation of WrapPanel and try to come up with a solution we can work upon.

Answer (score 0):

use this Code And Replace your Elements with Labels.

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label Background="Blue" Content="Toggle" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Label Background="Red" Content="Toggle" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Label Background="Brown" Content="Toggle" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Label Background="WhiteSmoke" Content="Toggle" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Label Background="Yellow" Content="Toggle" FontWeight="Bold"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

[After Resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrOAs.png)
[Before Resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVGwG.png)

Comment: I want the "Before Resizing" colors to span the entire window

Comment: I think it is not possible to do!